# Why admin added to the site?

Tags: magento-1.9, security

Today automatically added two admins to my site?
**Is my site hacked?**
What should I do to fix this bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First of all, remove the new admin users and change the password for the main admin user (and other admin users if there are any)
- Change the password of MySQL and update it in the app/etc/local.xml file.
- Change the password for the hosting panel and the MySQL management tool.
- Scan your store for the security patches (with the help of https://www.magereport.com/) and install if any patch is missing from the store.
- Magento provides a scan facility for stores to help the merchants keep their websites safe. Register yourself on https://magento.com/security and scan your website.

Note: Don't share your secret credentials over a non-secure medium and change them regularly.

I hope it would help.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not happen due to not updating it.    
Your work was more security-related and I did    
**thank you **
But by updating, I thought I'd fix this bug

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: I gave you a positive vote

Comment: Thanks, but someone else has downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got this problem, be sure to install the 8788 patch or update your shop.
This patch prevents attackers to create an admin account and execute code